# Add Excel File as an Attachment and also Paste in Email Body in outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a basic macro, where different files can be attached to send a mail

Where i am stuck is , if there is a possibility to copy that excel in E-mail body as well

Can you help tweak below Code, My destination path is in path_ = cell.Offset(1, 8).Value

The attachment only has table , the path is in the last columns,

***Based on the path how can I attached as well as copy the range and    paste in the EMAIL body***

---

[image]

```
 Sub SendEmail()
 Dim OutlookApp As Object
 Dim MItem As Object
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim email_ As String
 Dim email2_ As String
 Dim cc As String
 Dim subject_ As String
 Dim body_ As String
 Dim path_ As String
 Dim intX As String
 Dim intY As String
 Dim intZ As String
 Dim Body
 Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook



Sheets("Duplicates").Select
Range("A1").Select

'Create Outlook object
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Loop through the rows
 For Each cell In Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

 email_ = cell.Offset(1, 4).Value
 email2_ = cell.Offset(1, 5).Value
 cc = cell.Offset(1, 6).Value
 subject_ = cell.Offset(1, 7).Value
 path_ = cell.Offset(1, 8).Value



 'Create Mail Item and send it
 Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
 With MItem
 .To = email_ & ";" & email2_
 .cc = cc
 .Subject = subject_
 .htmlbody = "Dear All," & "</p>" _
        & "<br>" _
        & "Please find updated statement of accounts for your reference and payment persual.<br>" _
         & "<br>" _
        & "Kindly review all Line items and confirm payments  whichs needs to be settled before the end of the month.<br>" _
        & "<br>" _
        & "Kindly feedback on status of past due invoice and do let me know shall you require anything else.<br>" _
            & "<br>" _
                & "<br>" _
        & "<br>" _
        & "Thanks and Regards,<br>" _
        & "XXXXX<br>" _
        & "XXXXX,<br>" _
        & "XXXXX<br>" _
        & "XXXXX<br>" _
        & "XXXXX<br>" _
        & "XXXXX<br>" _


  .Attachments.Add path_

  .DeleteAfterSubmit = False
   .Send
   End With
   Next
   End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but it sounds like you want to add an excel range to the e-mail body? If so, then Ron De Bruins code is a good place to start: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail1.htm

Comment: Hello @Tragamor I have edited and update my query for better understanding. I have destination path in a column, I want to attach as well as copy the same excel sheet content in Email body as well. Please advise

Comment: You need to open the file, copy the range to the e-mail (as per previous link), close then attach the file. Google search for the relevant functions and test as you are going along. (`Debug.Print` is useful for monitoring while not interfering with the macro progress)